# Can't exit Vim with :!q

Tags: vim

I have made wrong changes in a text, and now I want to leave Vim without saving. I know I have to type :!q while in normal mode, but when I do this, it says:

```
[No write since last change]
/bin/bash: q: command not found

shell returned 127

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

And if I click ENTER or anything else, it returns back to Vim. What's going on?

Comment: Also see http://vi.stackexchange.com for future vim questions.

Comment: It is `:q!` (quit, I mean it!), not `:!q` (shell escape, pipe current line through `q`)

Comment: "they are unlikely to help future readers" but for some strange reason, it keeps receiving up-votes...

Comment: Two more upvotes only today! Maybe you moderators could re-think your parameters?

Comment: 10 upvotes as of today. This problem is obviously affecting lots of troubled Linux newbies!

Comment: 14 upvotes in 25 January 2018...

Comment: I don't agree with the "off-topic" flag of this post. It was the top hit on google on the exact same issue I had, being a vim noob. Thanks, @Rodrigo, for asking.

Comment: I don't understand how this is off topic, I just encountered the same problem. I literally couldn't return to the shell prompt and was asked the same thing as OP. I knew that I could `:!q` and issued the command several times before just deciding to close the terminal window.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use `:q!`. `:!q` tells `vim` to execute a command called `q` in your example.

See also `:help !` and `:help quit` for details

Comment: Of course. The ! is after, not before, the command. I was in a hurry...